# Dropdown AutoPostBack not working with IE10 for Win 7

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, internet-explorer-10

I just download IE10 for Windows 7 64bit [it is released today] and immediately found that my site's Dropdown AutoPost Back is not functioning. I am not getting any Error, but couple of warning in IE10's development Console. All of them are generated on ASP.NET Ajax toolkit elements.

I want to post it as bug to IE 10 team, but I found that my development server doesn't have this problem, only production server has this problem. Not mention the CODE IS EXACT same on both server. However development server is on Azure VM  with Windows 2012 and production server is shared web hosting with Windows 2008 [edition not known]

Does this make any difference on browser ?

EDIT: if it matters DO NOT TRACKER is off ...

EDIT2: I found that problem is only on IIS 7 based shared hosting, on Windows 2012 the site works just fine. SO probably IIS 7 doesn't know IE 10 and hence it doesn't render it properly.

Comment: Anyone any Idea what shall I check ?

Comment: I recently discovered that images buttons don't work with IE10 and .NET 4.0, but it works with .NET 4.5.
Maybe you have a similar problem. Is .NET 4.5 installed on prod server?

Comment: read my second edit, the problem is with IE10, IIS 7 based system. Not with IIS8

Comment: I don't know about IIS8, I just thought Windows 2012 probably has .NET 4.5 installed while Windows 2008 probably hasn't. That might make difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Hanselman explains this on his blog.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx